# How to turn autocomplete "ON" a form working with jquery and rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

As a beginner with jquery I am trying to figure out autocompletion with autocomplete-jquery in rails for a search form.

currently I have the following code for the search-text-field in my index.html.erb:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  class:"form-control", placeholder: "Suchen", data: {autocomplete_source: search_suggestions_path} %>
```

When I inspect the source-code in my browser I see the following:

[image]
notice where it says:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

in the last line. How can I fix this?

I already tried to include something like

```
autocomplete: "on"
```

as an option inside the form, however it does not work.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add javascript for better management like this

> `$("#search").autocomplete({`
>     `source: '/search_suggestions.json'`
>   `});`

The `search_suggestions_path` should return a json with key and value